# Usage of first terms of Taylor expansion to solve limit $\frac {e^{xy}-1}{\sin (x) \ln (1+y)}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I have come across the following solution for a limit:

$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0) } \frac {e^{xy}-1}{\sin (x) \ln (1+y)} = \\ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {xy}{x y} = 1
$$

where it has been used that $e^{xy}-1 \sim xy $; $\sin x \sim x$ and $\ln(1+y) \sim y $

It is clear that the simmilarities are obtained by taking up to the linear term of the Taylor expansion of each function.

Is this always valid? I mean, everytime I have a limit with $(x,y) \to (0,0) $, can I expand each -differentiable- function appearing inside the limit and a keep few of the first terms? Also, in the example above, all functions have been expanded up to the same term (linear), is this necessary, or may I keep an arbitrary number of terms for each individual function?

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that relates to the content of the question.

Comment: Hint: Does the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{(xy)^n}{\sin x \ln(1+y)}$$ exist for every $n\geq 1$ ?

Comment: Already done, sir.

Comment: @Ninad following the same logic, I guess I could reduce that limit to $$\lim \frac {(xy)^n}{x y} = (xy)^{n-1} = 0 \forall n>1$$. For $n=1$ this becomes $(xy)^0$ and $\lim (xy)^0 = 1$ So, I guess it does exist for every $n \geq 1$ right?